# How can I increase the spacing between my dropdown button and content?

Tags: html, css

I want to increase the transparent area between my dropdown button and its content so that the dropdown content lines up with the bottom of my navbar. I've tried using vertical-align: top in my code, which doesn't work.

Because I'm unsure of whether or not something in my navbar code is affecting the dropdown content, the code for both the dropdown/navbar is shown below.

```css
.navbar {
  verical-align: top;
  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0em;
  background-color: #f79256;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100vw;  

  padding: .5em;
}

.navbar a {
  vertical-align: top;
  
  float: center;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  
  color: #fbfffa;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;

  margin-left: 0.75em;
  margin-right: 0.75em;
}

.navbar a:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0; height: 3px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 1px;
  right: 0;
  background: #fbb68e;
  transition: width .2s ease;
}

.navbar a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: #fbb68e;
}

/* dropdown part of nav bar */
.dropdown {
  float: center;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;

  vertical-align: top;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-button {
  background: #f79256;
  color: #fbfffa;
  font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;

  vertical-align: top;

  position: relative;

  outline: none;
  border: none;

  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-right: 1em;
  
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  
  background-color: #fffef0;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px 0px #f0e6d6, 0px 6px 20px 0px #f0e6d6;
  z-index: 1;

  padding: 0px 0px 7.5px 0px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  float: none;
  
  font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #033d4f;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline 2.5px #15c1a4;
  text-underline-offset: 0.15em;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover:after {
    animation-name: none;
    width: 0;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
    <div class="navbar">
      <a href="index.html">home</a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropdown-button">about</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="purpose.html">purpose</a>
          <a href="team.html">our team</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="important.html">important</a>
      <a href="contact.html">contact</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Add `margin-top: 10px;` to `.dropdown-content` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by adding some margin to the `dropdown-content` element

```css
.navbar {
  verical-align: top;
  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0em;
  background-color: #f79256;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100vw;  

  padding: .5em;
}

.navbar a {
  vertical-align: top;
  
  float: center;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  
  color: #fbfffa;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;

  margin-left: 0.75em;
  margin-right: 0.75em;
}

.navbar a:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0; height: 3px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 1px;
  right: 0;
  background: #fbb68e;
  transition: width .2s ease;
}

.navbar a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: #fbb68e;
}

/* dropdown part of nav bar */
.dropdown {
  float: center;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;

  vertical-align: top;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-button {
  background: #f79256;
  color: #fbfffa;
  font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;

  vertical-align: top;

  position: relative;

  outline: none;
  border: none;

  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-right: 1em;
  
}

.dropdown-content {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  
  background-color: #fffef0;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px 0px #f0e6d6, 0px 6px 20px 0px #f0e6d6;
  z-index: 1;

  padding: 0px 0px 7.5px 0px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  float: none;
  
  font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #033d4f;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline 2.5px #15c1a4;
  text-underline-offset: 0.15em;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover:after {
    animation-name: none;
    width: 0;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
    <div class="navbar">
      <a href="index.html">home</a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropdown-button">about</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="purpose.html">purpose</a>
          <a href="team.html">our team</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="important.html">important</a>
      <a href="contact.html">contact</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This solves my problem, but now the dropdown content can't be clicked. It still shows up though.

Answer (score 0):

you can have click by adding some padding to the dropdown-content

```css
.navbar {
  verical-align: top;
  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0em;
  background-color: #f79256;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100vw;  

  padding: .5em;
}

.navbar a {
  vertical-align: top;
  
  float: center;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  
  color: #fbfffa;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;

  margin-left: 0.75em;
  margin-right: 0.75em;
}

.navbar a:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0; height: 3px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 1px;
  right: 0;
  background: #fbb68e;
  transition: width .2s ease;
}

.navbar a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: #fbb68e;
}

/* dropdown part of nav bar */
.dropdown {
  float: center;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;

  vertical-align: top;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-button {
  background: #f79256;
  color: #fbfffa;
  font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;

  vertical-align: top;

  position: relative;

  outline: none;
  border: none;

  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-right: 1em;
  
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  
  background-color: #fffef0;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px 0px #f0e6d6, 0px 6px 20px 0px #f0e6d6;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding: 0px 0px 7.5px 0px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  float: none;
  padding : 10px 0 ;
  font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #033d4f;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline 2.5px #15c1a4;
  text-underline-offset: 0.15em;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover:after {
    animation-name: none;
    width: 0;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
    <div class="navbar">
      <a href="index.html">home</a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropdown-button">about</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="purpose.html">purpose</a>
          <a href="team.html">our team</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="important.html">important</a>
      <a href="contact.html">contact</a>
    </div>
```

passing

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.